# IMAGEJ: convert an existing ImageProcessor picture (RGB) into an 8-Bit Grayvalue

Tags: java, imagej

I am a beginner and want to convert an existing ImageProcessor picture (RGB) into an 8-Bit Grayvalue Picture  (in ImageJ).

I tried different things but nothing worked:

```
ImageProcessor binaer = copy.getProcessor().convertToByte(false);
```

...Doesn't work

..so I wanted to Change Processor Type from ImageProcessor to ImagePlus..

```
ImagePlus imp = copy.getProcessor();
```

But this also didn't work.

I found this in the WEB:

> import ij.ImagePlus;
> import ij.process.ImageConverter;
>
> // ...
>
> ImagePlus imp = IJ.getImage();
>
> ImageConverter ic = new ImageConverter(imp);
>
> ic.convertToGray8();
>
> imp.updateAndDraw();

But I don't want to work with the original Picture, I want to work with the edited  ImageProcessor picture .

Can somebody please help me out

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that `copy.getProcessor().convertToByte(false);` didn't work? Because when I look into the ImageProcessor code, here is what I find:

```
public ImageProcessor convertToByte(boolean doScaling)
    {
    TypeConverter tc = new TypeConverter(this, doScaling);
    return tc.convertToByte();
    }
```

I did the test on my computer, and it worked fine. The RGB image was properly converted to gray level with 8 bits encoding.

What exactly do you expect? What are you trying to do? Do you want a binary image?

Comment: I have written a plugin what detects the cells und marks them black. Now I want to take that picture (which is in the ImageProcessor original_new). I want to set all the other pixels white and convert the picture to 8bit. I want to do that because ImageJ has the possibility to fill holes in binary pictures. And that is what I want

Comment: So you don't want to convert it to byte, but to BinaryProcessor. You can certainly do that doing a thresholding.